# Inserting Records Into Access Database Using Sql in Vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledbcommand

**The Problem**

So I am writing a Signup Form in vb.net and have an  connection to a database that i can read from no problem. Every time i run this code i get an error from the Insert into statement despite it working fine when i run it as a query in access.

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MasterDB.accdb")
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert into Table_usr(Username,Password,SurName,YearGroup) VALUES ('" & Username_txt.Text & "','" & Password_txt.Text & "','" & Surname_txt.Text & "','" & YrGroup_txt.Text & "')")
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Account Created")
            con.Close()
```

**Things Attempted**

I've tried subbing out the text box reading statements with plain text for just a simple update.

```
"Insert into Table_usr(Username,Password,SurName,YearGroup) VALUES ( ' 1 ','12345678','poiuytr','13')"
```

Still no luck. I've also tinkered with cmd.ExecuteReader but that didn't work either. I'm positive the table and column names are correct and the connection string. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: a) Dont concat bits of string to make a query, user SQL Parameters.  Your code will crash for a user name like `Charles D'Artagnan` b) Never store passwords as plain text, hash them.  c) Many of the DB provider obnjects need to be disposed

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have a couple of question. How would i read in the sql statement without it directly? Secondly i do plan on hashing but bumped into a little wall trying to get them to unhash so i decided to implement it later. finally i really don't get what you mean by the objects need to be disposed as in removed from the code? why so?

Comment: Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments. If you have another question please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), possibly including a link to your previous question for context.

Comment: Get your google fu on.  There are literally hundreds of questions here where the answers involve SQL params and also show disposing as needed.  A trip to MSDN would not hurt.  Hashing is one-way encryption - you dont unhash them.Do some research and post questions when you get stuck